# mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() is always false

Tags: android, google-signin

I want to check if user logged in with google or not but why the value of `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected` is always ***false***? I've connected `onStart`.

**onStart**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

**onCreate**

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

**the condition to check google login**

```
Log.i("TAG", "onCreate: google apiclient --> "+mGoogleApiClient);
    Log.i("TAG", "onCreate: google apiclient --> "+mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        showSocialUserDetail("google");
    } else {
        Log.i("TAG", "onCreate: google not login");
    }
```

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiU3C.png)

Comment: Did you check the callback answer? It may be an error somewhere..

Comment: `the condition to check google login` when do you check it? where?

Comment: @VladMatvienko i check it onCreate method

Comment: then why you think that it should be already initialized that time? It takes time to init it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko then when i must to check it?

Comment: that depends on what you want to do with it. But basically - once you get a callback of that it has been initialized.

Comment: @VladMatvienko i want to check if user logged in or not on activity start, i use 3 login method aws-cognito-userpool, facebook, and google. can u show me some example to check it?

Comment: then check it in the callback of the google client

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client
Remove you onstart method it's useless according to the doc, and you need a callback.

Comment: onConnected method? @VladMatvienko

Comment: oh ok i will remove it @neoteknic